# offset().left is returning different value on load than later

Tags: jquery

I am positioning a div right after load and the same div will be repositioned later when a link i klicked. The first positioning (the trigger event) have a left error of about 5px, while the klick-event is positioning properly. Why does this error occur? Is there someting else than the document I have to wait for in the beginning?

```
jQuery(document).ready($) {
    // move indicator & slide down
    $('#menu a').click(function(e){

        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        $('.active-indicator').animate({
            'left': $(this).offset().left,
            'width': $(this).outerWidth()           
        });
    });

    $('.active').trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: Can you create `jsfiddle` of the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you say "on load", you are actually positioning the element on document ready, when all elements haven't actually fully loaded, rendered, and been counted in to the document flow. When the click event is run to position the element, at that point the document layout has fully been created. In order to get this effect before the click event, try running the positioning code on `jQuery(window).load()` instead.

Comment: Thanks dude! That was what I was looking for, worked perfectly!